# where clause and aggregate functions

Tags: aggregate-functions, where-clause

Deposit(accno,cname,bname,amount)
Question:List the name of customer having max deposit in branch B1.
Answer: Select cname 
        from Deposit
        where amount in (select max(amount) 
                         from deposit 
                         where bname='B1');
IS THE ANSWER CORRECT?IF NO,PLEASE POINT ME OUT THE MISTAKE AND EXPLAIN THE CORRECT ANSWER FOR THIS.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct but it will probably be slow on a large dataset and if you don't have indexes on amount and bname.

I would rather use something like

```
SELECT cname FROM Deposit WHERE bname='B1' ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1;
```